# Why Image control with farsi character in ImageUrl not showed?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an image control. image file name is in farsi language. But image not show  in run time. I use IIS5 in Windows XP.
of course if image file name changed to english it showed.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/تقویم.jpg" 
      Width="200px" />
```

[image]

Comment: i think you need to check your image path correctly.

Comment: image path is correct.

Comment: problem is with farsi character

Comment: but i have tried it and its working fine with the same تقویم.jpg name.

Comment: It maybe a bug/limitation of the local web server. Try the IIS 7+ to see if he can show it. I check it by the way on iis5 and its not working to me either.

Comment: I use iis5 in windows XP.